# Positioning of jquery.simplemodal popup

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I am using jquery.simplemodal plugin and need help regarding the postion of the modal. I've different modals opening at the different position of the page i.e. some at top, middle or bottom. I want the position of the modal to be as per the position it is linked from i.e. bottom, top or middle. Right now, it's 22% from the top and if i click at the bottom, it opens the page at the top leaving 22% margin at the top.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#confirm-dialog input.confirm, #confirm-dialog a.confirm').click(function (e) {      
    confirm("");                
}); 
});



function confirm(message, callback) {
    $('#confirm').modal({
        closeHTML: "",
        position: ["22%",],
        overlayId: 'confirm-overlay',
        containerId: 'confirm-container',
        onShow: function (dialog) {
            var modal = this;                   
        }       
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I didn't realy get what you want to do

Comment: Diego, basically, i don't want the modal popup to open at the top only but rather flexible. relative to the position of the page. If i am clicking the link for modal popup from the bottom of the page, it should open at the bottom and not at the top after 22%.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the modal position as fixed. For more help I'd need to see the html, maybe you can make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Vinod: I don't really get what do I have to do to see the modal.